# ordering within select - case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to ordering within a select case statement by a single column only? lets say order in ascending by city only.

```
SELECT 
StudentLocation = 
CASE
  WHEN @IsRegistered IS NOT NULL AND @IsInClass IS NOT NULL THEN s.InClassLocation
  WHEN @IsRegistered IS NOT NULL AND @IsInClass IS NULL THEN s.OnlineLocation 
  ELSE s.City + ', ' + s.State
END
```

Comment: Do you have also a FROM, WHERE ?

Comment: Probably I don't understand the purpose. But why you dont do like this SELECT * FROM (SELECT 
StudentLocation = 
CASE
  WHEN IsRegistered IS NOT NULL AND IsInClass IS NOT NULL THEN s.InClassLocation
  WHEN IsRegistered IS NOT NULL AND IsInClass IS NULL THEN s.OnlineLocation 
  ELSE s.City + ', ' + s.State
END) order by

Answer (score 0):

You left out of your question the table and from/where clause, but assuming s is an alias to the table you're querying, you can use order the same way you always do it:

```
SELECT 
StudentLocation = 
CASE
  WHEN @IsRegistered IS NOT NULL AND @IsInClass IS NOT NULL THEN s.InClassLocation
  WHEN @IsRegistered IS NOT NULL AND @IsInClass IS NULL THEN s.OnlineLocation 
  ELSE s.City + ', ' + s.State
END
FROM someTable as s
ORDER BY s.City ASC;
```

*Corrected City*